# Show icon on product on each page

Tags: blocks, module

I'm using custom block to show my module logo over each product, now since `catalog_product_view` tag it shows the logo at product details page only, the problem is that I want to show the icon on each page on each product, whether it is home page, product list, detail, etc. how to achieve this using blocks

Here is the code

Module Configuration (app\etc\modules\NS_Mymodule.xml)

```
<config>
    <modules>
        <NS_Mymodule>
            <active>true</active>
            <codePool>community</codePool>
        </NS_Mymodule>
    </modules>
</config>
```

Configuration XML (app\code\community\NS\Mymodule\etc\config.xml)

```
<config>
    <modules>
        <NS_Mymodule>
            <version>1.0.1</version> 
        </NS_Mymodule>
    </modules>
    <global>
        <helpers>
            <Mymodule>
                <class>NS_Mymodule_Helper</class>
            </Mymodule>
        </helpers>
        <blocks>
            <mymodule>
                <class>NS_Mymodule_Block</class>
            </mymodule>
        </blocks>
    </global>
    <frontend>
        <layout>
            <updates>
                <mymodule>
                    <file>mymodule.xml</file>
                </mymodule>
            </updates>
        </layout>
    </frontend>
</config>
```

Block Class ( app\code\community\NS\Mymodule\Block\Showicon.php )

```
class Ns_Mymodule_Block_Showicon extends Mage_Core_Block_Template
{
    public function myfunction()
    {
        return "Hello tuts+ world";
    }
}
```

Layout XML ( app\design\frontend\rwd\default\layout\mymodule.xml)

```
<layout version="1.0.1">
    <catalog_product_view>
        <reference name="product.info">
            <block type="mymodule/showicon" as="ns_media" name="mymodule_showicon" template="mymodule/showicon.phtml" />
        </reference>
    </catalog_product_view>
</layout>
```

Template File (app\design\frontend\rwd\default\template\mymodule\showicon.phtml)

```
<h1>SHOW ICON HERE</h1>
```

and in the app\design\frontend\rwd\default\template\catalog\product\view.phtml

```
<?php echo $this->getChildHtml('ns_media') ?>
```

right after

```
<?php echo $this->getChildHtml('media') ?>
```

Comment: Use <default> layout handle to have your template and block on all the pages.

Comment: you mean rather of `<catalog_product_view>` we use `<default>`

Answer (score 1):

Use CSS instead of HTML - solves all your problems and the used class everywhere should be `product-image`

Comment: thanks for the reply, Can you tell me how to do that?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/6250843/1480397